# How can you adjust white balance setting for a custom iOS Camera App?

Tags: ios, image-processing, camera, avfoundation

I want to manually adjust the white balance using a slider before I start recording video from the camera. I have looked at the AVFoundation Framework but it does not allow to pick a value for WB. What frameworks/classes do I need to to adjust the WB in this way?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find any info on setting the camera's white balance (though I don't know for sure that it's not possible). But, you can always post-process with the [white balance Core Image filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIWhitePointAdjust) (aka CIWhitePointAdjust).

You can read about applying Core Image filters [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185).